# Two identical databases gives different execution plans

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

We have created a demo PostgressSQL database at DO to test performance, tune it up with indexes and etc. After we achieved good performance results we decided to roll up pre-staging identical database on new Postgress database server with the same 16gb of ram and 6cpu on SSD, created a database using create a script and imported data. We were not using PDump.

To our surprise, the query which we are suing for both databases runs 10 times slower on the pre-staging database than on demo.

```
EXPLAIN (buffers, analyse, timing )
SELECT
    DATE("DateStamp"), "Result", Count(*), Sum("ConversionCost")
FROM "Log"
WHERE "UserId" = 7841
  AND "DateStamp" > '2019-01-02'
  AND "DateStamp" < '2020-02-26'
GROUP BY 1,2
```

The execution plan for demo database

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=252123.56..660750.27 rows=3206490 width=21) (actual time=546.500..811.119 rows=714 loops=1)
"  Group Key: (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
"  Buffers: shared hit=5544, temp read=3903 written=3922"
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=252123.56..593948.38 rows=2672076 width=21) (actual time=545.942..810.651 rows=1811 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
"        Buffers: shared hit=16004, temp read=11035 written=11090"
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=251123.54..284524.49 rows=1336038 width=21) (actual time=539.140..793.857 rows=604 loops=3)
"              Group Key: (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
"              Buffers: shared hit=16004, temp read=11035 written=11090"
              ->  Sort  (cost=251123.54..254463.63 rows=1336038 width=9) (actual time=539.092..657.869 rows=1064916 loops=3)
"                    Sort Key: (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 23992kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 22808kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 22168kB
"                    Buffers: shared hit=16004, temp read=11035 written=11090"
                    ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using "IX_Log_UserId-all" on "Log"  (cost=0.56..72778.81 rows=1336038 width=9) (actual time=0.051..250.464 rows=1064916 loops=3)
                          Index Cond: (("UserId" = 7841) AND ("DateStamp" > '2019-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("DateStamp" < '2020-02-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                          Heap Fetches: 449
                          Buffers: shared hit=15974
Planning Time: 0.144 ms
Execution Time: 815.399 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/IBYt

The execution plan for staging database

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1682917.01..1760593.98 rows=3107079 width=21) (actual time=7180.989..7858.667 rows=714 loops=1)
"  Group Key: (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
"  Buffers: shared hit=21820 read=860249, temp read=8610 written=8627"
  ->  Sort  (cost=1682917.01..1690684.71 rows=3107079 width=9) (actual time=7180.970..7506.138 rows=3194749 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 68880kB
"        Buffers: shared hit=21820 read=860249, temp read=8610 written=8627"
        ->  Index Scan using "IX_Log_UserId" on "Log"  (cost=0.56..1317519.17 rows=3107079 width=9) (actual time=0.077..6423.617 rows=3194749 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (("UserId" = 7841) AND ("DateStamp" > '2019-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("DateStamp" < '2020-02-26 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
              Buffers: shared hit=21820 read=860249
Planning Time: 0.169 ms
Execution Time: 7868.180 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/SDae

Any idea where to look? The same resources, the same database with identical indexes, the same SQL query but different performance?!

Comment: Did you run `vacuum (full, analyse)`? Or at least `analyse`?

Comment: @Andronicus I did vacuum (full, analyse) but nothing improved.

Comment: Can you check `work_mem`? `show work_mem;`

Comment: @Andronicus both have set to 4MB

Comment: Drop the index ""IX_Log_UserId" on stage (presumably you can get away with doing this, since it is stage) and see what it does then.